# Estimate the large-time behavior of the unique viscosity solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation, viscosity-solutions

I am looking for some help to determine the large-time behavior of the unique solution for the equation in $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R$ $$u_t+\vert\nabla u\vert^\frac{2}{3}=0,\ \ \ \ u(0,x)=-\cos x$$
More specifically, I am thinking about how to determine the behavior of u at $(2015,0)$ or $(n,0)$ for any large integer $n$, but I have no idea that where to start.

Many thanks to the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Long comment**: The [Hamilton-Jacobi PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is derived from a canonical transformation involving a type-2 generating function $u(t,x)$ which makes vanish the new Hamiltonian
$K=H(u_x) + u_t$. Here, $H(p)=|p|^{2/3}$ is the original Hamiltonian.

For convex Hamiltonians $H$ which grow faster than the identity, the unique continuous viscosity solution can be obtained via the *Lax-Hopf formula*
$$
u(t,x) = \inf_{y\in \Bbb R} \left\lbrace t L \big(\tfrac{x-y}{t}\big) - \cos y\right\rbrace
$$
where the Lagrangian $L$ is the Legendre-Fenchel transform of $H$:
$$
L(q) = \sup_{p\in\Bbb R} \lbrace qp - H(p)\rbrace = \frac{4}{27}|q|^3 .
$$
However, the Hamiltonian is nonconvex here, which invalidates the previous approach. One may have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2195634/418542) for complements.

Comment: Hi Harry, if we want to determine the value of $u$ at $(2015,0)$, then shall we need to know the period? Or can $2015$ be regarded as a enough large time and so that $u$ vanishes at $(2015,0)$? Thank you:)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's clear to me now :)

Comment: Hi Harry. I checked your another post yesterday. Does your another post imply that $u(2018,0)=0$ since $u(n,0)$ is closed to $0$ when $n\ge 5$ by your another post? But my friend told me that $u(2018,0)=-1$. Is he wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I will reconsider this problem :)

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: The Hamiltonian is not convex...This answer does not seem correct.